# Referring to specific part of json ajax response in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am fairly new to JSON and jquery and javascript.
Using this in php.
I have a script that is being called by AJAX that is returning the following when I run console.log

```
var resp = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
```

Returns the followingin the console.:

```
{"status":"OK","action":["SHIPADDPOST","SHIPADDPOST=Shipment saved ADD"],"data":{"shipmentId":"76"},"timestamp":1444069313,"generationTime":"298ms"}
```

My question is the following:
How can I retrieve (in javascript) the value 76 (which is "shipmentID")?

Comment: Thank you so much.
Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the JSON.parse and extract the shipmentId as below.

```
var shop = '{"status":"OK","action":["SHIPADDPOST","SHIPADDPOST=Shipment saved ADD"],"data":{"shipmentId":"76"},"timestamp":1444069313,"generationTime":"298ms"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(shop);
alert(obj.data.shipmentId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSON.parse() but it might not be supported by all browsers.

Here an example:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
alert(obj.data.shipmentId);
```

Check:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse for more info on this method and compatibility.